# Yet another IE 'Object expected' error with no information

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, object-expected

Hey, I have been pulling my hair out with this error I am having on [this site](http://flowdev.co.uk/).

I am getting the dreaded `Object expected` error on line 1, character 21 in IE6 and IE7 only. I just wondered if anyone had any idea what this could be related to. I know about the whole trailing commas problem so I am very careful with that.

Any ideas will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you got a non-minified JS file?

Comment: @lonesomeday Ah yes, it's my own library which I have tested every part of in IE6 and IE7 so I don't know how it could be down to that. The uncompressed version can be found [here](https://github.com/Wolfy87/Spark/blob/master/spark-dev.js). My library is the only compressed file in that page.

Comment: I also get the error in IE8. Worth noting.

Comment: Huh, I am not. Very odd. Man I hate IE :/

Comment: Ah, I am getting in IE8 too...

Comment: So any ideas? At all? Can you see anything that looks slightly out of the ordinary?

Comment: I tried it with your non-minified version. I still got the error in IE8. It's something to do with `SparkFn.ready`. That's as far as I've got.

Comment: It's specifically to do with this part: `setTimeout("if(!alreadyRunFlag) callback()", 0);`.

Comment: Okay, thats narrowed it down a lot! You may want to post that as an answer and if I can get it to work from changing this line then I will accept.

Comment: Hmm, that did not fix it, I think messing with that function stopped the error though. Could it be down to my script tags attributes?

Comment: I *think* it's because the `callback` function isn't defined inside the (global?) scope where `setTimeout` executes the string of code.

Comment: Yep, thats the problem with the error, but it still does not explain why the tabs do not slide down. I thought the two problems where related but apparently not.

Comment: The tabs work in IE8, but do not work in IE7. I'll take another look.

Comment: Okay, uploaded a patched version of Spark that has a fixed ready function. The error is gone but the sliding down of the tabs is still not working. No errors though.

Comment: I've figured it out. I'll write an answer shortly.

Comment: Great - IE8 in IE7 mode only let the tab roll up once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We fixed the "Object expected" error in IE, so to answer the question in your comments:

**The problem is in your HTML.**

You have this HTML, once for each tab:

```
<div class='tab' id='introduction'>
    <h2 id='introduction'>Introduction</h2>
</div>

<div class='body' id='introduction' style='display:block'>
```

The problem is that you're specifying two elements with `id='introduction'`.

For various reasons, you should not do that:

- It's causing [validation errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fflowdev.co.uk%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).

  > Line 37, Column 27: Duplicate ID introduction.
  >   Line 36, Column 39: The first occurrence of ID introduction was here.
- It's breaking your tabs in IE7.
- There are also other reasons, but they aren't important here.

If I change it to (for example):

```
<div class='tab' id='introduction'>
    <h2 id='introduction'>Introduction</h2>
</div>
<div class='introduction body' style='display:block'>
```

*(remember to change all four instances in the same way)*

And if I change your JS to this (for example), it works:

```
// Show selected
Spark('.' + currentTab)
```

Comment: I somehow missed that there's a second duplicate id on the `h2`. You should also fix that, but it doesn't seem to be breaking IE.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head. I knew that you where not supposed to have multiple occurrences of id's yet I still did it, I don't quite know why. I just renamed one set of the id's to the id name plus `-content` and then appended `-content` to the selector for the slide down. It is all working perfect now. Thank you very much!

Comment: I like your version of the fix better, it makes more sense. Good job.