# behavior of browsers for css application when multiple elements share same id

Tags: html, css

I understand that IDs are supposed to be unique in HTML documents. But a lot of HTML pages are sloppy and don't follow the rule. My question is: how do browsers handle CSS applications for multiple elements sharing  the same id?

On my preliminary testing it seems that they apply the id specific CSS rule to all elements with the same id. This behavior seems to be common on IE 8, Chrome, Firefox, Opera.

Is this the sensible choice that browsers make to handle such sloppy HTML or are there exceptions to this behavior? What can be unintended consequences in CSS layout due to sharing of same id amongst multiple elements?

Comment: Browsers are just trying really really hard to be really really nice. No matter what kind of tag soup you throw at them, they'll always try their utmost to make it look half decent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an example of unintended consequences, see this question I answered:

[Yet another IE 'Object expected' error with no information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117104/yet-another-ie-object-expected-error-with-no-information)

> You have this HTML, once for each tab:
>
> ```
> <div class='tab' id='introduction'>
>     <h2 id='introduction'>Introduction</h2>
> </div>
>
> <div class='body' id='introduction' style='display:block'>
> ```
>
> **The problem is that you're specifying
>   two elements with `id='introduction'`.**
>
> For various reasons, you should not do
>   that:
>
> - **It's causing validation errors.**
>
>   > Line 37, Column 27: Duplicate ID introduction.
>   >     Line 36, Column 39: The first occurrence of ID introduction was
>   >     here.
> - **It's breaking your tabs in IE7.**

Comment: I really get afraid whenever I see Object expected errors in IE with no information :)

Answer (score 2):

You're right as far as CSS "pretty" display goes, the error recovery is to apply the CSS as if it were a class.

> What can be unintended consequences in CSS layout due to sharing of same id amongst multiple elements?

Not much to the actual CSS layout, as mentioned above but..

you might not be able to specifically target (isolate an element) if you need to, and/or the specificity of a selector needed to override a CSS rule with an ID already in it could only be done by adding a unique ID further up the ascendency (or adding an inline `<style>`)

also don't think you'll get on very well if you need to use jQuery or something like that, Javascript relies on the ID's for best functionality

ID's are also **[Fragment Identifiers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier)** - they won't work too well if they're not unique

Comment: Ya, multiple references say that getElementById() returns the first element with a given Id. So I presume that jQuery will behave accordingly.

Comment: You mean to say that browsers will only be able to use the first fragment identified by the id properly?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is something that breaks the rules it's not going to be something you can rely on. All you can do is test in each browser and it's handling might even change with the next version that comes out.

Handling it as you described seems sensible enough to me. There are probably more complications with how javascript handles this situation rather than css I would imagine.

I don't think there would be any unintended consequences. There are no problems with using the same class for many elements, why would ids be that different? I can't think of a single case where the basic rules of overriding styles wouldn't work as expected.