# ie error - object expected

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I am developing a website with html, javascript, jquery. The website is working fine on firefox, chrome, opera. But when I open the website by IE, IE pop up an error message "object expected, do you want to continue run the script"? When I click "no", the website lost some function. May I know how to detect which line of codes has the error?

IE error shows that the error is on line 50, here is the codes between line 36 to line 72 :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#messageposting').NobleCount('#characters_count',{
            on_negative: 'negative_value_color',
            on_positive: 'positive_value_color'
        });     
    });

function kk(e) {  //disable enter button on textarea
key = e ? e.which : window.event.keyCode;
if(key==13) {
return false;
}}

function mycarousel_itemLoadCallback(carousel, state)
{
    // Since we get all URLs in one file, we simply add all items
    // at once and set the size accordingly.
    if (state != 'init')
        return;
var str="";
    jQuery.get("usermessage.php?username="+str, function(data) {                                                    
        mycarousel_itemAddCallback(carousel, carousel.first, carousel.last, data);
    });
};


function mycarousel_itemAddCallback(carousel, first, last, data)
{
    // Simply add all items at once and set the size accordingly.
     items = data.split('|');

    for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        carousel.add(i+1, mycarousel_getItemHTML(items[i]));
    }
    carousel.size(items.length);
};
    </script>
```

Comment: Could you post the relevant code? Generally "Object Expected" means that you are trying to use an identifier that has not been defined or declared.

Comment: My codes has 2000 lines long, I don't think u will interested to read it... LOL.

Comment: @zac - Try and pinpoint the specific code running when the error occurs. Does it happen on load? If so this should shrink the total amount of code you'll need to post.

Comment: okay, I have update my question to show you the groups of codes that I suspect which causing the errors. Thank you.

Comment: You can go to the View > Source menu and look at the 50th line there.

Comment: @Ben Alpert, thank you. I have updated my question to show the codes that near to 50th line.

Comment: does the code still work if you ignore the error? i know i've written some scripts that are perfectly syntactically correct, yet ie still displays that error, but if i just ignore it, it works fine.

Comment: the error prompt asking me "do you want to continue run the script"? If I click "yes", then my website is still work perfectly. But if I click "no", then my website has some problems.

Comment: hei, i just uploaded all files to my online web hosting, the ie didn't show any error when i open the website on my online web hosting. The ie error appear only when i open the website on localhost through wamp.

Answer (score 3):

Is it possible you have the MIME type wrong for the script? The opening tag should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Also it's possible you have two HTML elements with the same `id`, which is not allowed.

(Sources: http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/538945-object-expected-error-ie-but-no-error-firefox-opera, [Yet another IE 'Object expected' error with no information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117104/yet-another-ie-object-expected-error-with-no-information))

Comment: I did checked <script type="text/javascript"> and all the id on my website by using firebug, no problem with them.

Answer (score -4):

In the java script function, after starting the function just add { like i mentioned below. Please see the space clearly. Its work well.

Correct One:

```
function iecheck(){

alert("After download click");

}
```

Its Wrong:

```
function iecheck()

{

 alert("After download click");

}
```

Comment: It's not incorrect and if the code gets minified then the whitespace will be removed anyways